# Display Nokogiri children nodes as raw HTML instead of &gt;tag&lt;

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, html-entities

I am changing an XML table into an HTML table, and have to do some rearranging of nodes.

To accomplish the transformation, I scrape the XML, put it into a two-dimensional array, and then build the new HTML to output.

But some of the cells have HTML tags in them, and after my conversion `<su>` becomes `&gt;su&lt;`.

The XML data is:

```
<BOXHD>
  <CHED H="1">Disc diameter, inches (cm)</CHED>
  <CHED H="1">One-half or more of disc covered</CHED>
  <CHED H="2">Number <SU>1</SU>
  </CHED>
  <CHED H="2">Exhaust foot <SU>3</SU>/min.</CHED>
  <CHED H="1">Disc not covered</CHED>
  <CHED H="2">Number <SU>1</SU>
  </CHED>
  <CHED H="2">Exhaust foot<SU>3</SU>/min.</CHED>
</BOXHD>
```

The steps I'm taking to convert this to an HTML table are:

```ruby
class TableCell

  attr_accessor :text, :rowspan, :colspan

  def initialize(text='')
      @text = text
      @rowspan = 1
      @colspan = 1
  end    
end
```

```ruby
@frag = Nokogiri::HTML(xml)

# make a 2d array to store how the cells should be arranged
column = 0
prev_row = -1
@frag.xpath("boxhd/ched").each do |ched|
  row = ched.xpath("@h").first.value.to_i - 1
  if row <= prev_row
    column +=1
  end
  prev_row = row
  @data[row][column] = TableCell.new(ched.inner_html)
end  

# methods to find colspan and rowspan, put them in @data
# ... snip ...

# now build an html table
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse ""
Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.with(doc) do |html|
  html.table {
    @data.each do |tr|
      html.tr {
        tr.each do |th|
          next if th.nil?
          html.th(:rowspan => th.rowspan, :colspan => th.colspan).table_header th.text
        end
      }
    end
  }
end
```

This gives the following HTML (notice the superscripts are escaped):

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="1" class="table_header">Disc diameter, inches (cm)</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="2" class="table_header">One-half or more of disc covered</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="2" class="table_header">Disc not covered</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="table_header">Number &lt;su&gt;1&lt;/su&gt; </th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="table_header">Exhaust foot &lt;su&gt;3&lt;/su&gt;/min.</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="table_header">Number &lt;su&gt;1&lt;/su&gt;</th>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="table_header">Exhaust foot&lt;su&gt;3&lt;/su&gt;/min.</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I get the raw HTML instead of the entities?

I've tried these with no success

```
@data[row][column] = TableCell.new(ched.children)
@data[row][column] = TableCell.new(ched.children.to_s)
@data[row][column] = TableCell.new(ched.to_s)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you understand what's happening:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root><foo></foo></root>')

doc.at('foo').content = '<html><body>bar</body></html>'
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root>\n  <foo>&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;bar&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</foo>\n</root>\n"

doc.at('foo').children = '<html><body>bar</body></html>'
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root>\n  <foo>\n    <html>\n      <body>bar</body>\n    </html>\n  </foo>\n</root>\n"

doc.at('foo').children = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new.create_cdata '<html><body>bar</body></html>'
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root>\n  <foo><![CDATA[<html><body>bar</body></html>]]></foo>\n</root>\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the builder, and simply built the HTML:

```ruby
headers = html_headers()

def html_headers()

  rows = Array.new
  @data.each do |row|
      cells = Array.new
      row.each do |cell|
          next if cell.nil?
          cells << "<th rowspan=\"%d\" colspan=\"%d\">%s</th>" %
                      [cell.rowspan,
                      cell.colspan,
                      cell.text]
      end
      rows << "<tr>%s</tr>" % cells.join
  end
  rows.join 

end

def replace_nodes(headers)

  # ... snip ...

  @frag.xpath("boxhd").each do |old|
      puts "replacing boxhd..."
      old.replace headers
  end

  # ... snip ...

end
```

I don't understand why, but it appears that the text I replaced the `<BOXHD>` tags with are parsed and searchable, as I was able to change tag names from data in `cell.text`.